# Move Nokia Backup (NBF) contents to Android Phone

Tags: sms, calendar

Recently I started using Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Y Duos) with Gingerbread. Prior to this switch I was using Nokia 6303c (S40 Device). Before I exchanged my Nokia for this phone I had made a backup using 'Sync & Backup' option provided by Nokia on phone onto its memory card. I had to do this as I did not have access to Nokia Suite to sync/backup contents to PC at that point in time.

Now I am not able to find any way to get the contents stored in .NBF file to my Android phone. Does anyone here know about any solution? Looks like NBUExplorer can open only .NBU files created by Nokia Suite.

Fortunately I could get all my contacts as they were synced a week before to a virtual machine running Windows (I use Ubuntu as my primary OS). However message sync had failed that time and I could not sync calendar as I do not have MS Outlook on virtual machine. Now I need a way to retrieve those messages and calendar entries.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the extension from `.nbf` to `.zip`. For detailed step-by-step instructions, [read this](http://nokiatoandroid.blogspot.in/).

1. Go to settings, sync and backup in old Nokia Symbian phone. Click on create backup and store the backup in memory card.
2. Connect the old phone to your PC through normal 'mass storage' mode and open the backup folder from memory card. Copy the `.nbf` file from memory card to your PC.
3. The trick lies in this step when you fool Nokia around.

   `.nbf` stands for Nokia Backup File.  Just change the extension from `.nbf` to `.zip` and extract using winrar/peazip.
4. Here you see a list of `.vcf` files in the extracted folder. Connect your Android phone to PC and transfer these files to SD card or internal memory.
5. Use this free <s>"[Import Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.waxworlds.edam.importcontacts)"</s> **(app is no longer available)** app from Google Play and transfer contacts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that's worked. I am able to transfer contacts from nokia to samsung.