# Import .vcf files from old Nokia fails

Tags: applications, contacts, sd-card, import

I have to transfer 50 contacts from an old Nokia phone to a Motorola running Android 5.
I managed to Export an nbf backup from the Nokia and Export all contacts vcf files from that nbf file.
But now every time I try to import those vcf files from the default contacts App, Theres a notification "will import 1.vcf soon" and then "finished importing 1.vcf".
But the imprted contacts wont show up in the App.
Further more I can only import single contacts as when I select more than one it will say importing but never finish
Thank you for your help :)

Edit: Just tested the import on my note 4 with stock Samsung OS and it worked just fine

Comment: This [post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/move-nokia-backup-nbf-contents-to-android-phone) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks but the APP mentioned there didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work with the app [Tranfer Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maineavtech.android.grasshopper) by Maine Avenue Technologies SL. It's pretty much self-explanatory and easy to use but works only with Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Ok sry will update it

Comment: Note: _If you have less than 100 Contacts, operation is 100% free._ else _fee is about 1$, depending on your region and currency._

Comment: Well as I said in my post normally every mobile device is capable of importing vcf files

Comment: No, I'm not saying it's not supported by all mobiles. But you forgot to mention that limitation of the app in which the import work free only if the contacts numbered less than 100. More than that would be no free of cost. ;)

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that its just the way I got it to work (after 2 hours) and that I dont want to get people to buy that app.

Comment: I just wanted to update my question for anybody coming to this and wondering how I solved it, I didnt even know it would cost for more contacts

Comment: You are welcome to add your own answers. And I just wanted to mention the limitations of the app if someone is gonna import more contacts without knowing its cost. No criticism intended, but added the comment as a sidenote for future readers.

Comment: Yeah sure, it was constructive critisism I just dont See why my answer got downvoted(I think it will misleed future readers into thinking its wrong while it clearly worked for me.. :))

Comment: FYI: I didn't downvote. But someone who downvote should have commented the mistake in your answer. Anyway, will upvote it now. You can accept your own answer after two day of posting it.

Comment: I dont know who did either, btw thank you for correcting my answer if it was you. I will accept it tomorrow :)